# Access violation writing location 0x000001C0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cocos2d-x

I'm working on this and have a problem that I cant figure out.

I got this in the header

```
class PGEnemy : Public CCSprite
{
private:

    int pHP;
    int pLoot;
    int pAttack;
    int pSpeed;

    PGEnemy();
    ~PGEnemy();

public:

    bool setSpeed (int speed);

    static PGEnemy* factory(eType type); //create an enemy
    void init(int type); //read info from json (json cpp)

};
```

And in the code I got this

```
void PGEnemy::init(int type)
{

    try
    {
    Reader reader;
    Value initial;
    unsigned long size = 0;

    unsigned char *config_doc = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData("enemy.json", "r", &size);

    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse((char*)config_doc, initial);

    string s = TO_STRING(type);

    cout << s << endl;

    if(parsingSuccessful)
    {
        this->pHP = initial[TO_STRING(type)]["hp"].asInt();
        this->pLoot = initial[TO_STRING(type)]["loot"].asInt();
        this->pAttack = initial[TO_STRING(type)]["attack"].asInt();
        this->pSpeed = initial[TO_STRING(type)]["speed"].asInt();
    }
    }
    catch (exception)
    {


    this->pHP = 100*type;
    this->pAttack = 100*type;
    this->pSpeed = 100*type;
    this->pLoot = 100*type;


    }
    //*/
}
```

In the moment of doing `this->pHP = initial[TO_STRING(type)]["hp"].asInt();`
or any other that I shall put a value in those integers (even in the catch), it crash with the error

> `Access violation writing location 0x000001C0.`

from a open source code for using json, file Json_value.cpp

```
Value::asInt() const
{
   switch ( type_ )
   {
   case nullValue:
      return 0;
   case intValue:
      JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE( value_.int_ >= minInt  &&  value_.int_ <= maxInt, "unsigned integer out of signed int range" );
      return Int(value_.int_);
   case uintValue:
      JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE( value_.uint_ <= UInt(maxInt), "unsigned integer out of signed int range" );
      return Int(value_.uint_);
   case realValue:
      JSON_ASSERT_MESSAGE( value_.real_ >= minInt  &&  value_.real_ <= maxInt, "Real out of signed integer range" );
      return Int( value_.real_ );
   case booleanValue:
      return value_.bool_ ? 1 : 0;
   case stringValue:
   case arrayValue:
   case objectValue:
      JSON_FAIL_MESSAGE( "Type is not convertible to int" );
   default:
      JSON_ASSERT_UNREACHABLE;
   }
   return 0; // unreachable;
}
```

The most "unknow" is that the error also happened when I simply try to do `this->pHP = anyIntegerValue`

```
PGEnemy* PGEnemy::factory(eType type)
{
    PGEnemy* enemy = (PGEnemy*)CCSprite::create("Target.png");
    enemy->init(type);
    return enemy;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `*` to highlight code.

Comment: @0x4 removed in my latest formatting edit.

Comment: ok, wont highlight code using *

Comment: Show us the implementation of `asInt` please.

Comment: Can you narrow down error by breaking nested calls in your assignment to determine the source of the crash?  Then step with debugger and examine the state after each call.  You will likely find the source fairly quickly.  The solution may be more difficult :)

Comment: This is a code of a project that couple of friends and I are madding, I always got problems with the json so I usually let it to crash and goes to the catch and "hardcode (for testing the class im making)" but it EVEN crash when I try to this->pSpeed = 10; for example with the error named: "Access violation writing location 0x000001C0" and don't understand why :/

Comment: You are dereferencing a NULL pointer, an entirely standard bug.  Unclear where or why, use a debugger.  The hard one to find is *this* being null.

Comment: Hans Passant, can you explain yourself please? I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: He means you're accessing memory at offset 0x1c0 through a pointer which is NULL. Consequently, the error your seeing indicates that access is invalid an aborts your program. A null pointer to some object using code assuming it is valid, then accessing some member data somewhere offset from the base of the object will exhibit the kind of behavior your seeing. Running it under a debugger will almost assuredly show you exactly *where* this is happening, along with a stack trace to tell you how you got there.

Comment: But.. Im confused now. I got the instance of the class, all the values are empty, = NULL, even if they are globals, but if I try to set a values it dosent allow? Im really not getting..  PD: English not my first / second language

Comment: show how you instantiate a PGEnemy object. Show the constructor. By any chances, is this NULL? Why do you use "this" in an instance method?